# sending data from server to a js file.. getting Passport to display Facebook image on Google maps infobox

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, google-maps, passport.js

I am using passport.js to log a user into a google maps API.
When you login it geolocates and puts a marker on the map with your facebook image and name. However I am struggling to do this!

The map.js that has all the map logic cannot see the server.js that has all the user logic. So Map.js does not know what a user is.

Below we have managed to hardcode it. How can we make it Dynamic?
Full repo at https://github.com/5-minute-catchup/ANEWREPO
Thank you

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              content: profile.id + 'user.name <IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="Left" SRC="https://graph.facebook.com/10153052143439442/picture"> <br>Phoebe '
            });
            map.setCenter(pos);
```

We do save the image to our own mongoDB when the user logs in. however we cannot add this to the marker and get it to return.. the call we make to out database to return image is

```
<img src="<%= user.image %>">
```

How can I pass what the server knows to the map.js about the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in map.js is:

```
  var getUser = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: '<IMG BORDER="0" ALIGN="Left" SRC=' + getUser.dataset.image + '>'
        });
```

and in index.ejs:

```
<div id="map-canvas" data-name='<%= user.name %>' data-image=<%= user.image %>>
        </div>
```